# Generating Java interface with SWIG

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig

I'm using SWIG to make a Java wrapper of a C++ library (about Json (de)serialization) to use it on Android. I defined an abstract class in C++, representing an object which can be (de)serialized :

```
class IJsonSerializable {
public:
    virtual void serialize(Value &root) = 0; 
    virtual void deserialize(Value &root) = 0; 
};
```

Now, I'm trying to generate from this class a Java interface. Here's my SWIG interface:

```
%module JsonSerializable
%{
#include "JsonSerializable.hpp"
%}

%import "JsonValue.i"

class IJsonSerializable {
public:
    virtual void serialize(Value &root) = 0; 
    virtual void deserialize(Value &root) = 0;
};
```

But the generated Java code is (obviously, as I was not able to find out how to tell SWIG that's an interface) a simple class, with the two methods and a default constructor/destructor:

```
public class IJsonSerializable {
  private long swigCPtr;
  protected boolean swigCMemOwn;

  public IJsonSerializable(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn) {
    swigCMemOwn = cMemoryOwn;
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }  

  public static long getCPtr(IJsonSerializable obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }  

  protected void finalize() {
    delete();
  }  

  public synchronized void delete() {
    if (swigCPtr != 0) {
      if (swigCMemOwn) {
        swigCMemOwn = false;
        JsonSerializableJNI.delete_IJsonSerializable(swigCPtr);
      }  
      swigCPtr = 0; 
    }  
  }  

  public void serialize(Value root) {
    JsonSerializableJNI.IJsonSerializable_serialize(swigCPtr, this, Value.getCPtr(root), root);
  }  

  public void deserialize(Value root) {
    JsonSerializableJNI.IJsonSerializable_deserialize(swigCPtr, this, Value.getCPtr(root), root);
  }  

}
```

How can I generate a valid interface with SWIG ?

Comment: Why? Java has JSON APIs already, just use one of the many available.

Comment: @ChrisDennett: I'm already using this library for other usages in C++. I've got other libraries to port in the near future, so I'll have the same problem with them.

Comment: I don't understand - what do you want it to generate here? SWIG generates proxies that match the declarations and definitions you show it, which is what it's done here. Is it a case of [this problem](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#adding_downcasts)? I can give you a concrete example if you make what you're looking for a bit clearer.

Comment: I'm trying to make a Java class implement a C++ defined interface. In fact, I have some (Java) methods waiting for a IJsonSerializable (to be sure they have serialize and deserialize methods).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can achieve what you're looking for with SWIG+Java using "[Directors](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#java_directors)", however it's not quite as straightforward mapping from the C++ abstract classes onto Java as you might hope. My answer therefore is split into three parts - firstly the simple example of implementing a C++ pure virtual function in Java, secondly an explanation of why the output is like that and thirdly a "work-around".

## Implementing a C++ interface in Java

Given a header file (`module.hh`):

```
#include <string>
#include <iosfwd>

class Interface {
public:
  virtual std::string foo() const = 0;
  virtual ~Interface() {}
};

inline void bar(const Interface& intf) {
  std::cout << intf.foo() << std::endl;
}
```

We'd like to wrap this and make it work intuitively from the Java side. We can do this by defining the following SWIG interface:

```
%module(directors="1") test

%{
#include <iostream>
#include "module.hh"
%}

%feature("director") Interface;
%include "std_string.i"

%include "module.hh"

%pragma(java) jniclasscode=%{
  static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("module");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
      System.err.println("Native code library failed to load. \n" + e);
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
%}
```

Here we've enabled directors for the whole module, and then requested they be used for `class Interface` specifically. Other than that and my favourite "load the shared object automatically" code there's nothing particularly noteworthy. We can test this with the following Java class:

```
public class Run extends Interface {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    test.bar(new Run());       
  }

  public String foo() {
    return "Hello from Java!";
  }
}
```

We can then run this and see it's working as expected:

> ajw@rapunzel:~/code/scratch/swig/javaintf > java Run
>   Hello from Java!

If you're happy with it being neither `abstract` nor an `interface` you can stop reading here, directors do everything you need.

## Why does SWIG generate a `class` instead of an `interface`?

SWIG has however made what looked like an abstract class into a concrete one. That means on the Java side we could legally write `new Interface();`, which makes no sense. Why does SWIG do this? The `class` isn't even `abstract`, let alone an `interface` (See point 4 [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#java_directors_faq)), which would feel more natural on the Java side. The answer is twofold:

1. SWIG supplies mechanics for calling `delete`, manipulating the `cPtr` etc. on the Java side. That couldn't be done in an `interface` at all.
2. Consider the case where we wrapped the following function:

   ```
   Interface *find_interface();
   ```

   Here SWIG knows *nothing* more about the return type than that it's of type `Interface`. In an ideal world it would know what the derived type is, but from the function signature alone there's no way for it to figure this out. This means that in the generated Java *somewhere* there's going to have to be a call to `new Interface`, which wouldn't be possible/legal if `Interface` were abstract on the Java side.

## Possible workaround

If you were hoping to provide this as an interface in order to express a type hierarchy with multiple inheritance in Java this would be quite limiting. There's a workaround however:

1. Manually write the interface as a proper Java interface:

   ```
   public interface Interface {
       public String foo();
   }
   ```
2. Modify the SWIG interface file:

   1. Rename the C++ class `Interface` to be `NativeInterface` on the Java side. (We ought to make it visible only to the package in question too, with our wrapped code living in a package of its own to avoid people doing "crazy" things.
   2. Everywhere we have an `Interface` in C++ code SWIG will now be using `NativeInterface` as the type on the Java side. We need typemaps to map this `NativeInterface` in function parameters onto the `Interface` Java interface we added manually.
   3. Mark `NativeInterface` as implementing `Interface` to make the Java side behaviour natural and believable to a Java user.
   4. We need to supply a little bit of extra code that can act as a proxy for things which implement the Java `Interface` without being a `NativeInterface` too.
   5. What we pass to C++ must always be a `NativeInterface` still, not all `Interface`s will be one though (although all `NativeInterfaces` will), so we provide some glue to make `Interface`s behave as `NativeInterfaces`, and a typemap to apply that glue. (See [this document](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#java_pgcpp) for a discussion of the `pgcppname`)

   This results in a module file that now looks like:

   ```
   %module(directors="1") test

   %{
   #include <iostream>
   #include "module.hh"
   %}

   %feature("director") Interface;
   %include "std_string.i"

   // (2.1)
   %rename(NativeInterface) Interface; 

   // (2.2)
   %typemap(jstype) const Interface& "Interface";

   // (2.3)
   %typemap(javainterfaces) Interface "Interface"

   // (2.5)
   %typemap(javain,pgcppname="n",
            pre="    NativeInterface n = makeNative($javainput);")
           const Interface&  "NativeInterface.getCPtr(n)"

   %include "module.hh"

   %pragma(java) modulecode=%{
     // (2.4)
     private static class NativeInterfaceProxy extends NativeInterface {
       private Interface delegate;
       public NativeInterfaceProxy(Interface i) {
         delegate = i;
       }

       public String foo() {
         return delegate.foo();
       }
     }

     // (2.5)
     private static NativeInterface makeNative(Interface i) {
       if (i instanceof NativeInterface) {
         // If it already *is* a NativeInterface don't bother wrapping it again
         return (NativeInterface)i;
       }
       return new NativeInterfaceProxy(i);
     }
   %}
   ```

Now we can wrap a function like:

```
// %inline = wrap and define at the same time
%inline %{
  const Interface& find_interface(const std::string& key) {
    static class TestImpl : public Interface {
      virtual std::string foo() const {
        return "Hello from C++";
      }
    } inst;
    return inst;
  }
%}
```

and use it like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Run implements Interface {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    ArrayList<Interface> things = new ArrayList<Interface>();
    // Implements the interface directly
    things.add(new Run()); 
    // NativeInterface implements interface also
    things.add(test.find_interface("My lookup key")); 

    // Will get wrapped in the proxy 
    test.bar(things.get(0));

    // Won't get wrapped because of the instanceOf test
    test.bar(things.get(1));
  }

  public String foo() {
    return "Hello from Java!";
  }
}
```

This now runs as you'd hope:

> ajw@rapunzel:~/code/scratch/swig/javaintf > java Run
>   Hello from Java!
>   Hello from C++

And we've wrapped an abstract class from C++ as an interface in Java exactly as a Java programmer would expect!

Comment: You can probably automate the writing of the `NativeIntefaceProxy` class using something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291637/alternatives-to-java-lang-reflect-proxy-for-creating-proxies-of-abstract-classes)

Comment: Exactly what I needed, and so well explained ! Thank you so much.

Comment: I think SWIG 3.1 is likely to change this answer substantially when released: https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/java/swiginterface.i

Comment: @Flexo could you guide me how to use swig to set a java object to C++?

Comment: @QuangHuynh that's pretty much what [this section of the SWIG manual](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Java.html#Java_directors) does - you either need to be more specific in your question (and ask it as a question!) or there's nothing insightful I can add over what's already written.

Comment: @Flexo like this question but using SWIG: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110908/swig-typemap-java-object

Comment: @QuangHuynh that *is* using SWIG