# Java class generation with SWIG from a c++ class with a base class and an interface

Tags: java, c++, swig

I'm porting a c++ application to Java. I used SWIG to generate some Java classes and the JNI wrappers.

In c++ I have a class called Lion which extends Animal and implements Killable. I got a warning saying that multiple inheritance doesn't exist in Java. No problem so far, Lion will only extends Animal in my Java class.

Classes generated with SWIG :

```
public class Killable {
  private long swigCPtr;
  protected boolean swigCMemOwn;

  public Killable(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn) {
    swigCMemOwn = cMemoryOwn;
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  protected static long getCPtr(Killable obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }

  protected void finalize() {
    delete();
  }

  public synchronized void delete() {
    if (swigCPtr != 0) {
      if (swigCMemOwn) {
        swigCMemOwn = false;
        cppinterfaceJNI.delete_Killable(swigCPtr);
      }
      swigCPtr = 0;
    }
  }

  public long getKillableId() {
    return cppinterfaceJNI.Killable_getId(swigCPtr, this);
  }

  public void kill() {
    cppinterfaceJNI.Killable_kill(swigCPtr, this);
  }
}


public class Lion extends Animal {
  private long swigCPtr;

  public Lion(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn) {
    super(cppinterfaceJNI.Lion_SWIGUpcast(cPtr), cMemoryOwn);
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  public static long getCPtr(Lion obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }

  ...
}
```

Let's now say I want to have an array of Killable.
Since Java classes generated with SWIG store a pointer to the original c++ class, I should be able to do something like :

```
LinkedList<Killable> list = new LinkedList<Killable>();
Killable k = new Killable(Lion.getCPtr(myLionObject), false);
list.add(k);
System.out.println(k.getKillableId()) // Return a long, no crash here but I got a huge number (wrong number)
k.kill(); // Crash
```

There are no error when I do that but when I try to access to a method of my object k the library crashes. I think the crash occurs because no proper implementation are found but I don't understand why because I give a valid pointer to the new object. Any idea why the crash occurs or a workaround I could use here ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you give class and methods descriptions? Like interface Killable { public void kil()}... class Animal implements Killable...

Comment: Oh, and if Lion implements Killable, wth with Killable k = new Killable(Lion.getCPtr(myLionObject), false);

Comment: just poking around with the cptr does not cast properly.

Comment: (In general in SWIG questions a *minimal*, complete header file, interface file and some complete, compilable code in the target language is more useful than just the auto generated output and a fragment the target language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've seen the combination of [SWIG+Java doesn't result in pure virtual classes becoming interfaces automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168517/generating-java-interface-with-swig).

The problem is that manipulating the objects with `getCPtr()` directly like you've shown is akin to writing something like:

```
Lion *l = new lion;
intptr_t ptr = (intptr_t)l;
Killable *k = (Killable*)ptr;
```

In C++ - it's bad form to use C style casts like that because they mask the undefined behaviour. It's exceedingly unlikely to work as intended and even if it did that would be worse than just crashing since you'd have undiagnosed undefined behaviour in your code base. Fortunately with SWIG there's a trivial workaround where you want to make such a cast (that would normally simply be an automatic conversion) possible still.

Supposing we have the following header file:

```
#include <iostream>

class Killable {
public:
  virtual ~Killable() {}
  virtual void die() = 0;
};

class Animal {
public:
  virtual ~Animal() {}
  virtual void moo() { std::cout << "The dog says: meow\n"; }
};

class Lion : public Animal, public Killable {
  virtual void die() { std::cout << "Deaded\n"; }
};
```

We can wrap this successfully with the following SWIG interface:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "test.h"

%extend Animal {
  Killable *toKillable() {
    return dynamic_cast<Killable*>($self);
  }
}
```

Here, the `%extend` adds another member function that takes care of the cast that won't be getting exposed automatically otherwise. If the conversion is sane then a valid `Killable` is returned. If it isn't then `null` will be returned instead.

We can use that in Java:

```java
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class run {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    System.loadLibrary("test");
    LinkedList<Killable> list = new LinkedList<Killable>();
    Lion l = new Lion();
    l.moo();
    Killable k = l.toKillable();
    list.add(k);
    k.die();
  }
}
```