# Generate C# Interface from C++ using SWIG

Tags: c#, c++, interface, mocking, swig

How do I use SWIG to generate a C# interface (or at least a C# mock-able base class) from C++ using SWIG?

Given:

C++:

```
class IWidget
{
public:
     virtual void Flob() = 0;
};

class Widget : public IWidget
{
public:
     void Flob() {};
};
```

I would like to output C#:

```
public interface IWidget
{
     void Flob();
}

public class Widget : IWidget
{...}
```

Note:  Solution does not have to be an interface, but I do need to be able to use mocking frameworks such as Moq or Rhino.Mocks to mock out the base of the C# Widget class.  My attempts only yielded generated C# with no public constructors.

Comment: Try something after reading the SWIG docs which show clearly how to do this, then update your post with specific problem.

Comment: @Schollii Could you point me to the right section?  I looked over examples and read C# section, didn't see C# interface mentioned anywhere.

Comment: I think you essentially want an equivalent of http://stackoverflow.com/a/8246375/168175 - although I think that should largely port by doing s/java/cs/ I think there are some smarter options open for C# possibly and some updated bits in latest version of SWIG that I'll investigate later.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to get the output you list by using one or more of:

- `csclassmodifiers`
- use `%ignore` on the pure virtual methods, add necessary method declarations using cscode .
- `csinterfaces typemap`
- `csinterfaces_derived typemap`

However this may not be the easiest way to achieve the goal of making your class mockable. Consider extending your post to clearly identify what is the c# that you need to achieve this if `interface` is not used.

Also take a look at this post: http://swig.10945.n7.nabble.com/Multiple-inheritance-and-C-any-easy-workarounds-available-td11516.html.

Sorry I can't provide an actual code answer, hopefully the above gets you there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the docs more or less. You need to refer to the Java section [here](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.1/Java.html#Java_interfaces).

```
%module MyWidgetModule
%include <swiginterface.i>

%{
    #include "IWidget.h"
%}

%interface_impl(IWidget); // Use namespace qualified class name
%include "IWidget.h"
```

This also works when you're using shared pointer support for SWIG. It will generate a class and the intended interface.

Answer (score -2):

Start with the

[Swig tutorial](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html)

"Interface file" and then "Building a C# module" are the imp things there. Below is mentioned for compile/link in the same document. Do the same in Visual Studio.

```
$ swig -csharp  example.i
$ gcc -c -fpic  example.c example_wrap.c
$ gcc -shared example.o  example_wrap.o   -o libexample.so
$ cscc -o runme *.cs
```

Comment: I think there's confusion on my use of "interface".  I know how to use SWIG to output C#, but the C# it outputs is a class, not an interface.  If the base C++ is pure abstract, I want the generated C# to be an interface, not a class.