# How to build the Java wrapper for OpenCV 3.0?

Tags: opencv, swig, opencv3.0

I am using OpenCV 3.0 in my Java application through the `opencv-300.jar` and `opencv_java300.dll`. They come with the standard installation. But some extra modules are not in the standard installation. So I build an OpenCV 3.0 with the [opencv-contrib repo](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib).

But the build generates about 40 binaries. How can I generate something like `opencv-300.jar` and `opencv_java300.dll` for Java adoption? Do I need to turn to [SWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168517/generating-java-interface-with-swig) or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can build OpenCV + extra modules with VS2013.
Extra modules can be downloaded from: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/releases

1. Run "cmake-gui.exe" in VS2013 command prompt.
2. Click the "Configure" button.
3. Select VS2013 as the generation templaet.
4. Modify the config entries as necessary.
5. Click "Generate" to generate the VS2013 project files.
6. Open the generated project files and build.

Ref:

**(*)** http://answers.opencv.org/question/66571/how-to-build-the-java-wrapper-for-opencv-30/

http://answers.opencv.org/question/66630/javalangunsatisfiedlinkerror-when-using-binaries-built-from-source/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508130/keypoints-was-cleared-after-descriptoerextractor