# How To change specific method implementation in the swig generated proxy class?

Tags: java, c++, abstract-class, swig

I am trying to wrap the following abstract class using the director feature:

```
Listener.h:

class Listener {
  protected:
  void onEvent() = 0;
}
```

my interface file looks like this:

```
module(directors="1") Listener_Java
feature("director") Listener;
%{
#include "Listener.h"
%}
%include "Listener.h"
```

the resulting method in the generated Java proxy class looks like:

```
...
protected void onEvent() {
Listener_JavaJNI.Listener_onEvent();
}
```

what I would like to do is to generate the method as abstract with no body, like this:

```
protected void onEvent();
```

Is there any easy way to do this? the reason I want to make the method abstract is to force any derived class to override this method, because if it isn't overrided, when calling this event in other place in my c++ code, an exception arises (because it attempts to invoke pure virtual function that is not implemented)

Comment: There is an option for a workaround that I've written before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168517/generating-java-interface-with-swig

Comment: Your workaround looks promising, I will try it on sunday. You mentioned in a comment to your answer that "SWIG 3.1 is likely to change this answer substantially", what do you mean? I am willing to use 3.1 as it features the doxygen integration.

Answer (score 1):

From the [SWIG documentation about Directors](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Java.html#Java_directors_faq):

> Why isn't the proxy class declared abstract? Why aren't the director
>   upcall methods in the proxy class declared abstract?
>
> Declaring the proxy class and its methods abstract would break the JNI
>   argument marshalling and SWIG's downcall functionality (going from
>   Java to C++.) Create an abstract Java subclass that inherits from the
>   director-enabled class instead. Using the previous Foo class example:
>
> ```
> public abstract class UserVisibleFoo extends Foo {
>   /** Make sure user overrides this method, it's where the upcall
>    * happens.
>    */
>   public abstract void method_upcall(Foo foo_object);
>
>   /// Downcast from Foo to UserVisibleFoo
>   public static UserVisibleFoo downcastUserVisibleFoo(Foo foo_object)
>   {
>     try {
>      return (foo_object != null ? (FooDerived) Foo.downcastFoo(foo_object) : null);
>     }
>
>     catch (ClassCastException exc) {
>       // Wasn't a FooDerived object, some other subclass of Foo
>       return null;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> This doesn't prevent the user from creating subclasses derived from
>   Foo, however, UserVisibleFoo provides the safety net that reminds the
>   user to override the method_upcall() method.

Comment: I have read this part in the documentation. "JNI argument marshalling and SWIG's downcall functionality (going from Java to C++.) " - my class won't be using as argument, and the method won't be called from java (the only way it will be called is from the c++ , that's why I need director), that is why I asked for workarounds. Thanks anyway.