# Intercepting method calls

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have this code

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.callTheMethod();
```

Is there any way I can intercept the `Foo.callTheMethod()` call without subclassing or modifying `Foo` class, and without having a `Foo` factory?

EDIT: sorry forgot to mention this is on Android platform.

Comment: In addition to answers already placed here there is another great question + awnser(s) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291637/alternatives-to-java-lang-reflect-proxy-for-creating-proxies-of-abstract-classes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you considered [aspect-oriented-programming](https://web.archive.org/web/20120124141354/http://www.voelter.de:80/data/articles/aop/aop.html) and perhaps [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) ? See [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-aspectj/) and [here](http://deansserver.co.uk/~dean/2011/07/18/aspect-oriented-android-development-tool-integration/) for AspectJ/Android info.

Answer (score 30):

Use Java's [`Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class. It creates dynamic implementations of interfaces and intercepts methods, all reflectively.

Here's a [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies).

Comment: Yes, I've looked for `Proxy`, but in all examples I've seen you have to create the instance (e.g. `Foo` instance) using the `Proxy` object. This is not acceptable in my case. I cannot modify the example code shown above.

Comment: @m0skit0 If you can't insert the `Proxy` generation before the method call, then you're right, this solution won't work since you need to replace the `Foo` instance with the new `Proxy` instance. Sorry :)

Comment: Yes, actually the `Proxy` class will need to be a `Foo` factory. Thanks for your answer anyway :)

Comment: @Brian the tutorial link is broken

Comment: @JoãoMatos -- Thanks for the heads up :) I switched it over to [a newer Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies) that has Java 8+ syntax using Lambdas.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/aop.html) . You dont have to subclass your class by hand - but Spring will generate them behind the scenes and add code to do the interception.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is Possible through [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/). I will explain it with some code snippet:

```
public Aspect
{
    Object around()call(* Foo.callTheMethod())
    {
        // do your work
        return proceed(); 
    }                       
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is basically the same as the [accepted one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12372266/898478) :)