# Design pattern to delegate different operations to different classes

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a class ABC that can do operation a(), b() and c() (operation == method), which are all closely related. I also have simimar classes DE and FGH. In the future, it is possible new classes are added with additional operations. Classes never share operations (for example, there is no class ADF)

My program should be able to perform all these operations, and the timing is "kind of random", meaning I have no estimate beforehand of which operation will be executed when/how many times.

I tackled this program by creating a wrapper class "OperationInvoker". My program can only access this invoker, and it has one method for each operation. The advantage of this is encapsulation: if new operations are created or existing one or edited, onlt the wrapper class needs editing.

My question is whether a "huge" wrapper is the best pattern to solve this?

I looked into the observer pattern for this by I think this is not a suitable case because the classes ABC, DE, FGH ... never have any mutual interests. Like, if operation A needs to be executed, all registered classes will receive event A and only 1 class (namely, ABC) will be actually interested in this event. all other registered classes will discard the event. This seems like overkill/overhead with all the registering and observing.

The delegation pattern also suffers the same problem: i don't have many classes doing the same operation in a different way, so there is no point in having a flexible delegation system.

Are there other, better patterns, or is this just a simple case of having a delegating wrapper class?

EDIT: someone asked what exactly ABC does. Well, I have a WSDL file that describes SOAP web services. I use a tool to convert this file to java classes. This means I cannot control the content of these classes as they are auto generated. So I wrote a class WebServiceInvoker which acts as a wrapper around these web services. This wrapper class has 3 methods: do web service A, do web service B, and do web service C.

As the program expands, more and more wsdl files enter the picture. Of course none of the web services do the same thing. The only reason why they are not all bundled together in one big wsdl file is because some web services just don't belong logically next to other web services. So I wind up with the following classes:

- A wrapper class which can call web service A, B and C
- A wrapper class which can call web service D, E
- A wrapper class which can call webservice F, G and H

It is possible in the future more wsdl's (and thus wrapper classes) appear. The reason why is there an additional wrapper around all the other wrappers is because every service needs to be called with a "session id". So every wrapper needs to know this information. So the superwrapper holds this information, and can call all web services. This also works very well as an api: the program who uses the web services knows nothing of the services, it just has 1 public method available for each web service through the superwrapper. The program of course is aware of what each web service returns (a list, a string, nothing...).

Comment: Do you want to abstract the fact that ABC and DE are provided by separate objects? If so, a wrapper seems good. If it's ok that the client knows that ABC and DE are separate, why not just pass them in (constructor injection), possibly with interfaces IABC and IDE?

Comment: all operations require a single shared parameter: the name of the user invoking the operation. The wrapper class seemed like an ideal place to store this username. I don't really need my program to not know whether ABC and De are separate, but I don't think it hurts either (separation of concerns).

Comment: It sounds to me that the classes ABC, DE and FGH are doing very different things. Is it really usefull then to have a shared handling? Let's assume you have the classes Car, House and Pizza. Is it a good idea to handle them all together? Or could it be easier if you just distinguish between the classes and handle each on it's own? Well, just my thoughts on this.

Comment: An other pattern that could fit is the use of a proxy, maybe even a [proxy extending a class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3291637/3080094).

Comment: @Korashen: Each operation is a web service. Each web service has a shared part (creating the soap body, adding the connection parameter...) buteach is also vastly different (some return ture/false, others have more ocmplex responses, some can throw errors...). Should they be handled together? I feel like they should.

Comment: Ah, ok, yes, you're right, it makes sense to handle the web service communication together.

Comment: I lurk in [tag:design-patterns], and find that questions that specify something real (as opposed to ABC) are much easier to answer. Is it possible to provide more concrete details to your question?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: Yes, I will add them now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow for easier code maintenance, I suggest altering the wrapper to something like this:

```
public class Operations {
    private ABC abcInst;
    private DE deInst;
    private FGH fghInst;

    protected Operations(ABC abc, DE de, FGH fgh) {
        this.abcInst = abc;
        this.deInst = de;
        this.fghInst = fgh;
    }

    public ABC getABC() { return abcInst; }
    public DE getDE() { return deInst; }
    public FGH getFGH() { return fghInst; }
}
```

This way there is no mainenance needed here (unless a new class is added) and all calls from a caller will only need the additional `.getABC().a()` instead of `.a()` etc. wich emphasizes on the fact that the operations are performed by different classes but still allows to access all functionality by passing around the `Operations`-instance.

Comment: in the class Operations, What is the advantage of returning ABC so the caller can do ABC.a() over providing a method a() in allOps which calls ABC.a() itself?

Comment: @user1884155 If you add a method `ab()` to class `ABC` you don't have to change anything in `Operations`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a definite architecture on one side that you are trying not to leak out into other components. The natural method of avoiding leaks like this is to add one more degree of separation.

Essentially, you can still keep one huge wrapper if you like but you need to consider what you wish to expose and only expose that.  It looks like all you want to expose is a list of known operations so how about something like:

```
// Your setup - trimmed down.
interface ABC {

    public void a();

    public void b();

    public void c();
}

interface DE {

    public void d();

    public void e();
}

interface FGH {

    public void f();

    public void g();

    public void h();
}

// Your current wrapper.
class AllOps {

    public ABC getABC() {
        return null;
    }

    public DE getDE() {
        return null;
    }

    public FGH getFGH() {
        return null;
    }
}

// One further degree of separation.
enum Op {

    A {

                @Override
                void op() {
                    ops.getABC().a();
                }

            },
    B {

                @Override
                void op() {
                    ops.getABC().b();
                }

            },
    C {

                @Override
                void op() {
                    ops.getABC().c();
                }

            },
    D {

                @Override
                void op() {
                    ops.getDE().d();
                }

            },
    E {

                @Override
                void op() {
                    ops.getDE().e();
                }

            },
    F {

                @Override
                void op() {
                    ops.getFGH().f();
                }

            },
    G {

                @Override
                void op() {
                    ops.getFGH().g();
                }

            },
    H {

                @Override
                void op() {
                    ops.getFGH().h();
                }

            };
    // Hide the huge wrapper.
    private static AllOps ops = new AllOps();
    // Only expose the operations.
    abstract void op();
}

public void test() {
    Op.A.op();
    Op.F.op();
}
```

Not sure what pattern this would be but if you only expose the enum I think you have achieved your disconnect.

Additional operations can be added as new enums that implement `op` in any way you like. They may even not use the huge wrapper.

Comment: in the class allOps, What is the advantage of returning ABC so the caller can do ABC.a() over providing a method a() in allOps which calls ABC.a() itself?

Comment: @user1884155 - None at all - the code is intended to demonstrate a technique that adds a further degree of disconnect. I used your wrapper as an example, the technique could obviously just as easily use one of each of the three types instead and still demonstrate no change from the users perspective - thus proving the value of a disconnect, its implementation can be changed without affecting its interface.